# Close WPF popup when user clicks on it

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, popup

How do I close the following popup when its content is clicked?

```
<Button Name="myButton" Content="Hover to open" />
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=myButton}" Placement="Bottom">
    <Popup.Resources>
        <DataConversion:BooleanOrConverter x:Key="booleanOrConverter" />
    </Popup.Resources>            
    <Popup.IsOpen>
        <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource booleanOrConverter}">
            <Binding Mode="OneWay" ElementName="myButton" Path="IsMouseOver"/>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="IsMouseOver" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Popup.IsOpen>
    <!-- some content here -->
</Popup>
```

I wanted to avoid writing code in the code behind file and binding visual and behavioral things like IsOpen property or MouseDown event to the ViewModel.

Comment: Code-behind has received a largely undeserved notoriety lately.  It's not an evil force bent on wanton code obfuscation.  The key distinction for me is whether an interaction being implemented by code-behind is part of the actual behavior of the ViewModel logic or if it's merely glue for communicating an interaction.  In the latter case, it's often much cleaner to have a little glue code than to have a complex knot for the sake of loose coupling.

Comment: Closing a window is the job of the UI, not of the ViewModel.  VM = business logic.  UI = UI logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `EventTrigger` on your `Popup` that triggers a storyboard that contains a `BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames` that sets `IsOpen` to `false`, [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372628/help-me-please-with-a-popup). Easier to just use code-behind ;o)

Answer (score 2):

You could just make the `Popup.Child` a `Button` (style it to not look like one), handle its `Click` event and set `IsOpen` to `false` (preferably using [`SetCurrentValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) to not destroy the binding).

You can either do this in code behind or using a behavior/trigger action.